# How to check if a JSON key has unique values in a JSON file using javascript?

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON file like(for example) :

```
"fields": {
"asset": {
    "values": [{
            "asset": {
                "id": "Info_text",
                "type": "text",
                "value": "ABCD"
            }
        }, 
        {
            "asset": {
            "id": "Info_input",
            "type": "input",
            "value": "ABCDE"
            }
        }
    ]
}
}
```

How can I iterate over the values of "id" and check if they a unique or not in javascript?

Comment: Make an object whose keys are the IDs. Loop through the JSON data, test if the current ID is already in the object. If it is, it's a duplicate. If not, add it.

Answer (score 1):

here is complete demo without additional library, you can find if any key/value pair is unique in a json object and how many occurences were found :

```js
var jsonData = {
  "fields": [
    {
      "asset": {
        "id": "Info_input",
        "values": [
          {
            "asset": {
              "id": "Info_text",
              "type": "text",
              "value": "ABCD"
            }
          },
          {
            "asset": {
              "id": "Info_input",
              "type": "input",
              "value": "ABCDE"
            }
          },
          {
            "asset": {
              "id": "Info_input",
              "type": "input",
              "value": "ABCDE"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}

function findKeyValueCount(key, value, obj) {
 var count = 0;
 var keys = Object.keys(obj);
 keys.forEach(function(k) {
  var v = obj[k];
  if(typeof v === 'object') {
   count += findKeyValueCount(key, value, v)
  }
  else if(k === key && v === value) {
   count += 1;
  }
 });
 return count;
}

function isUnique(key, value, obj) {
 return findKeyValueCount(key, value, obj) === 1;
}


console.log(findKeyValueCount('id', 'Info_text', jsonData));
// -> 1

console.log(findKeyValueCount('id', 'Info_input', jsonData));
// -> 3

console.log(findKeyValueCount('value', 'ABCDE', jsonData));
// -> 2

console.log(findKeyValueCount('xxx', 'yyy', jsonData));
// -> 0

console.log(isUnique('id', 'Info_input', jsonData));
// -> false

console.log(isUnique('id', 'Info_text', jsonData));
// -> true
```

Have fun !

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've used 'inarray' package to find if an element is in the array to fine unique elements.

Comment: You're welcome. If you found a better way, please add a new answer and accept it, it will help others users with a similar question.